# How can I prevent an auxiliary program to disconnect the wired connection in Ubuntu?

Tags: network-manager

I have a program that disconnects the wired connection automatically at times, and I have only ehternet, no wifi. I thought about editing this:

```
[device] wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

in

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

from

/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

But should it rather be:

"**wired**.scan-rand-mac-address=no ?

How can I in other words make network config to automatically restart wired connection if it is disconnected?

Thanks

Comment: What is the program? Why is it disconnecting? Do you need it? You can confine the program in a number of ways including `Apparmor`, for example.

Comment: Expressvpn, it disconnects the entire wired connection when I issue disconnect (the VPN), but it cannot differentiate between VPN and the whole connection. I need it

Comment: You need to tell ExpressVPN to fix that. You shouldn't have to dance around their broken software.